# C# serial port loop interrupt

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, windows

I started with c# a few weeks ago, so I'm not pretty well in this programming language, but I need it for work.
now I have the following problem:
I want to send and receive data from a Serial port in a Loop (some voltages in a loop like 200ms) the whole time. during the time the Loop is running, which should be all the time,  cant use my GUI to send/receive other data from that Serial port. 
I tried a timer already, which executes the Loop every 200ms, but if I pressed another button in the GUI to send data to the Serial port, something went wrong.
What I want to do now is to check at the end of the Loop if a button was pressed, then stop the Loop for a moment, execute the function of the button and then restart the Loop.
Any ideas how I can manage this? 
thx in advanceI

Part of the Loop:

```
serialPort1.Write("GetVolt 8V\r");
serialPort1.ReadLine();
tb12V_8V_V.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
serialPort1.Write("GetVolt 5V3\r");
serialPort1.ReadLine();
tb5V3_V.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
serialPort1.Write("GetVolt 3V5\r");
serialPort1.ReadLine();
tb3V5_3V3_V.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
```

and a button:

```
try
{
    serialPort1.WriteLine("SetVolt 8V On\r");
    serialPort1.ReadLine();
    serialPort1.ReadLine();
    btn8V_Off.Visible = true;
    btn8V_On.Visible = false;
    btn12V_Off.Visible = false;
    btn12V_On.Visible = true;
}
catch (TimeoutException)
{
    errorMessage();
}
```

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

One of many possible ways...

In the button:

```
flag= true;
```

In the loop:

```
if (flag)
{
  serialPort1.WriteLine("SetVolt 8V On\r");
  serialPort1.ReadLine();
  serialPort1.ReadLine();
  btn8V_Off.Visible = true;
  btn8V_On.Visible = false;
  btn12V_Off.Visible = false;
  btn12V_On.Visible = true;
  flag= false;
}
else
{
  serialPort1.Write("GetVolt 8V\r");
  serialPort1.ReadLine();
  tb12V_8V_V.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
  serialPort1.Write("GetVolt 5V3\r");
  serialPort1.ReadLine();
  tb5V3_V.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
  serialPort1.Write("GetVolt 3V5\r");
  serialPort1.ReadLine();
  tb3V5_3V3_V.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I have more than one Problem here, first I have more than just one button. ok, i think thats not that hard to manage, but the main Problem is that i cant press Buttons during the Loop is running...

Comment: That's a different problem. You can look at putting the loop code in a background worker thread, perhaps. Or you can go back to putting the loop code in a timer (unlooped). In any case, you may get into problems waiting for serial input, if it is late or missing, say.